# Restarted WordPress server, now PHP/MySql problems

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I had a running Wordpress website, all I did was restart the server and now I get "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

Before restarting I copied the /etc/passwd file from a mirror server because that had extra ftp permissions in it I wanted to transfer.

I've trying lots of different "fixes" but none work.
extension=mysql.so and extension=mysqli.so are uncommented in php.ini

/etc/init.d/mysql status produces "error: 'Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'"

I don't know our root password for mysql, I have taken over from someone else who set this up and I can't contact him.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Most probably your php.ini is not being picked up due to some change in settings. Check apache configuration to see if it lists the correct php.ini path as you expect?

Comment: Do a `phpinfo()` in the browser to examine what extensions you have loaded. Please edit your distro into your question, so people can give distro-specific commands for you to try. Ubuntu?

Comment: Did the resetting root password steps now I get "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)"

Comment: phpinfo is displayed in browser so it's being read correctly

Comment: This is horrific, our main website is down and all I did was restart the server! No solution is working!!

Answer (score 0):

In first, you can receive debian-sys-maint password from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
Then log onto you DB server and set up wordpresss user access.

Comment: Thank you but like I said I can't login to mysql as don't have the root password, followed steps above and just get "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)"

Comment: You have MySQL server installed on localhost or on a remote machine?
If MySQL server is installed locally, you need do this: `service mysqld start` and then try to connect him: `mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p[password_here]` The Debian default user have root permissions for MySQL databases and over this account you can reset default root password and manage other users.
If Mysql installed on remote host, to connect him you need: mysql -u [user] -h [host] -p[password]

Comment: Installed on localhost. "service mysqld start" isn't recognised, I do "service mysql start" and it says "Job failed to start". Did "mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p", entered password from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf, it says "Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: Make sure that in your /var/log/mysql.log and /var/log/mysql.err no errors. And you can try this [link](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/442/Resetting_a_forgotten_MySQL_root_password) to reset your forgotten pass.

Comment: /var/log/mysql.log and /var/log/mysql.err are both blank. First command from the link "/etc/init.d/mysql stop" produces "Stopping MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) mysqld [fail]"

Comment: "/etc/init.d/mysql start" produces "Starting MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) database server mysqld [ OK ]"